# Rubymine Find in Path: Exclude a particular filename pattern?

Tags: rubymine

Using RubyMine's "Find in Path" search feature, I'd like to do a search on all files whole filenames do not match a particular pattern. For example, all files whose names do not include the string "test".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by prefixing the file name match pattern in the "File mask" field with a `!` (exclamation point) character.

For example, to have the search match all files that don't include the string "test", use the pattern: `!*test*`

[image: Rubymine Find in Path dialog with File Mask field highlighted]